# Member Class Functions

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

So I am trying to figure out how to create a function that Returns an Array of all integers that are in common with self and ary and returns an empty Array if there are no intersections. This is what I have so far:

```
IntArray* findIntersections(IntArray &ary) {
int length1 = ary.getLength(); // Getting the length of &ary.
int length2 = getLength([//Right here, there's something to do with "this" because I've created a mArray already and defined it, but I'm not sure how to re-call it here.]); // Getting the length of self.
int length4 = 0; // Because anarchy
if (length1 > length2){ // An if statement to match length4 with the longest array.
    length4 = length2;
} else {
    length4 = length1;
}

IntArray* newArray; // New IntArray on the heap.
newArray = new* int[length4];

int k = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < length1; j++){ // Two for loops getting the iterator on the same page.
    for (int i = 0; i < length2; i++){
        if (ary.get(j) == [//The this from earlier, whatever it is][i]){ // Checking to see if digits match each other.
            newArray[k] = (ary[j]); // Writing the digit into the NewArray.
            k++; // Adding one to the k count to progress the the iterator.
        }
    }
}
return newArray; 
}
```

In the end, there I know there's gonna be three arrays. The one being passed in, the one being created and passing out, and then that this reference which I honestly don't even know what it is. I'm thinking it's an mArray I created earlier, but I'm not exactly sure. Any help on this would be absolutely fantastic!

Also, here's my .hpp file:

```
class IntArray {
private:
    int *mArray;
    int mSize;

public:

    IntArray(int *array, int size);
    int get(int index);
    int getLength();
    int indexOf(int value);
    bool remove(int index);
    IntArray* findIntersections(IntArray &ary);
    bool isSubsequence(IntArray &ary);
    ~IntArray();
};
```

And my .cpp file:

```
#include "IntArray.hpp"

IntArray::IntArray(int *array, int size) {
int *newArray = new int [size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    newArray[i] = array[i];
}
}

int IntArray::get(int index) {
return mArray[index];
}

IntArray::~IntArray() {
delete[] mArray;
}

int IntArray::getLength() {
return mSize;
}

int getLength(int *array){
int length = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
return length;
}

int indexOf(int *array, int value){
int length = getLength(array);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if (value == array[i]){
        return i;
    }
}

return -1;
}

bool remove(int *array, int index){
int length = getLength(array);

if (0 <= index && index < length){
    for (int i = index + 1; i < length; ++i){
        array[i - 1] = array[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

IntArray* findIntersections(IntArray &ary) {
int length1 = ary.getLength(); // Getting the length of &ary.
int length2 = getLength([//Right here, there's something to do with "this" because I've created a mArray already and defined it, but I'm not sure how to re-call it here.]); // Getting the length of self.
int length4 = 0; // Because anarchy
if (length1 > length2){ // An if statement to match length4 with the longest array.
    length4 = length2;
} else {
    length4 = length1;
}

IntArray* newArray; // New IntArray on the heap.
newArray = new* int[length4];

int k = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < length1; j++){ // Two for loops getting the iterator on the same page.
    for (int i = 0; i < length2; i++){
        if (ary.get(j) == [//The this from earlier, whatever it is][i]){ // Checking to see if digits match each other.
            newArray[k] = (ary[j]); // Writing the digit into the NewArray.
            k++; // Adding one to the k count to progress the the iterator.
        }
    }
}
return newArray; 
}

bool isSubsequence(int *array) {
int length = getLength(array);
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] != array[i + 1])
        return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't call my getLength function so I had to modify it to fit the situation.

Comment: `getLength` doesn't take arguments. Did you mean `ary.getLength()` instead of `getLength(&ary)`? Please read on how to provide a useful [mcve].

Comment: `(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))` does not return the length of the array. This scheme only works for array types, not pointers to the start of an array. `mArray` is a pointer, not an array. It's size of just the size of a pointer, regardless of how many elements the pointed array contains. There is no portable mechanism for obtaining the number of elements in a C array from a pointer to it's elements.

Comment: Please fix indentation before posting code

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::vector<int>`?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of findIntersection is not defined as a member function, you have defined it as a global function. The member function *declaration* named findIntersection is not defined. In short: you forgot `IntArray::` before the function name